# Fantasy manga about a kid in the demon army who controlled black flames and wore a ragged cloak and a skull with horns

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, demons

I read this manga long ago where the main character was a kid in the demon army with the nickname from the enemies 'Black Demon,' because he controlled black flames and wore a ragged cloak and a skull with horns.

Comment: Do you have more details?

Comment: Yes, if there's anything more you can tell us about this manga (i.e. whether it was in full colour or not, whether it involved isekai or reincarnation or not, what the MC did before joining the demon army, why he joined the demon army, etc), please do [edit] your question to add whatever details you can. Every little helps with story-ID questions.

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Might this be ***[The Maou Army's Strongest Magician Was a Human](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/au31sqn/maougun-saikyou-no-majutsushi-wa-ningen-datta)***...?

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/maou-gun-saikyou-no-majutsushi-wa-ningen-datta):

> I'm known as the Maou Army’s strongest magician. Like, I have the demonic power capable of capturing a fort alone. Clearing away enemies with immense magic, I am without a doubt a monster awed by friend and foe. However, I have a secret I can’t tell the other demons: I'm actually from Earth. Using modern knowledge to keep my secret, I'm being treated as a great commander and the driving force of the Maou’s army.

I've yet to find a part where the main character is specifically referred to as the 'Black Demon,' but he is a powerful mage/general in the Demon King's army, who wears a cloak with horns and a skull mask to disguise the fact that he's secretly human.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is this ***[The Rise of the Unemployed Wise Man](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/ebpzda8/shitsugyou-kenja-no-nariagari)***...?

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/manga/129173/Shitsugyou_Kenja_no_Nariagari__Kirawareta_Sainou_wa_Sekai_Saikyou_deshita):

> Karna was a boy who was given the title of "Sage" from heaven, and was scouted by the hero party who had great expectations for his skills. However, his skill "necromancer" was creepy and he was immediately exiled. Karna, who got lost on the road without getting a reward, had accidentally invaded the Demon King territory and was targeted by the demons! He faced a demon with mighty power but defeats it with magic that overwhelmed it by far. Meanwhile, Cecilia the devil, who saw the whole scene, offers Karna a large annual salary. And thus Karna decided to become an enemy of humanity as a magician with the Demon King army.

The main character is kicked out of the Hero's party and subsequently recruited into the Demon King's army, at which point he starts wearing a cloak and a mask with horns to disguise the fact that he's human. The face on the mask is more monstrous or demonic than skull-like, but the term 'Black Demon' is used in the story.

[image]